# How can I do complex animations within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, three.js

so I'm wanting to have various sized triangle particles fly in from a random direction (all over the screen) and then assembles to spell the word "Zoid". I have been looking and three.js looks to be the API that I should use for this kinda stuff.

What three.js example should I be looking at?

I am not looking for someone to make this for me, I am only wanting the name of the technique/animation.

Comment: Do you have any experience with key frame based animation softwares? I have exported animations to Flash .SWF files and then used Swiffy ( https://developers.google.com/swiffy/ ) to convert from .SWF to a handy javascript animation.

Answer (score -1):

http://anime-js.com/ take a look at this seems like a pretty good framework for animated javascript